Animate 3D model on scroll | React.js
I am trying to make the 3d component listen to the user's scrolling, such that scrolling down plays the animation forward. When the user stops scrolling, the animation should also stop, and when the user scrolls back up, the animation should play back, or reverse. So far I've only managed to pause the animation on load.
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useGLTF, useAnimations } from '@react-three/drei';
import anPlatoform from '../assets/3d/rigged_sci-fi_lift_-_mobile_platform_-_elevator.glb';

const AnimatedPlatform = (props) => {
  const platRef = useRef();
  const { scene, animations } = useGLTF(anPlatoform);
  const { actions } = useAnimations(animations, platRef);
  const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useState(0);
  const [isScrolling, setIsScrolling] = useState(false);
  const scrollTimeout = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const actionNames = Object.keys(actions);
    let demoAction;
    if (actionNames.length > 0) {
      demoAction = actions['Demo'];
      if (demoAction) {
        demoAction.clampWhenFinished = true;
        demoAction.paused = true;
        console.log('Demo animation found and paused');
      } else {
        console.warn('Demo animation not found in the GLB file');
      }
    } else {
      console.warn('No animations found in the GLB file');
    }

    const handleScroll = () => {
      const scrollAmount = window.scrollY;
      setScrollPosition(scrollAmount);
      setIsScrolling(true);

      
      if (scrollTimeout.current) {
        clearTimeout(scrollTimeout.current);
      }
      scrollTimeout.current = setTimeout(() => {
        setIsScrolling(false);
      }, 200); 
    };

    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
      if (scrollTimeout.current) {
        clearTimeout(scrollTimeout.current);
      }
    };
  }, [actions]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const demoAction = actions['Demo'];
    if (demoAction) {
      const maxScroll = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
      const scrollFraction = scrollPosition / maxScroll;


      const animationDuration = demoAction.getClip().duration;
      const newTime = scrollFraction * animationDuration;


      demoAction.time = newTime;


      if (isScrolling) {
        demoAction.play();
      } else {
        demoAction.paused = true;
      }
    }
  }, [scrollPosition, isScrolling, actions]);

  return (
    <group ref={platRef} {...props} dispose={null} position={[-1, -2, 4]} scale={[0.3, 0.3, 0.3]}>
      <primitive object={scene} />
    </group>
  );
};

export default AnimatedPlatform;


